# Mvc Jquery Ajax Funtion Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Can not Work function for ajax,can I work ? I want to show a notification with mvc ajax..But I use ActionResult comeback Return RedirectToAction("myAction","myControl"),Can I make.
Thanks for help ..
My Sample Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Kategori/KategoriEkle',
        type: 'POST',
        data: "{}",
        datatype: 'html',
        success: function () {
            var unique_id = $.gritter.add({

                title: 'Welcome to Home!',
                text: 'Message',
                //image: '/assets/img/ui-sam.jpg',
                sticky: true,
                time: '',
                class_name: 'my-sticky-class'
            });

            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Kategori.cs

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult KategoriEkle(Kategori kategori)
    {
        KutuphaneContext db = new KutuphaneContext();
        var con = db.Kategori.Where(x => x.KategoriAdi == kategori.KategoriAdi).Count();

        if (con <= 0 && kategori.KategoriAdi != null)
        {                
            _kategoriRepository.Insert(kategori);
            _kategoriRepository.Save();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Kategoriler", "Kategori");
    }

}
```

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page (and update the DOM). Ajax calls do not redirect. If you want to redirect, do not use ajax - make a normal submit.

Comment: how to make a normal submit @StephenMuecke ..Thanks

Comment: Normal submit, means write your normal method just like asp.net. You are writing on button click over there.

Comment: For mvc beginners, there is good project by Microsoft - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/nerddinner/introducing-the-nerddinner-tutorial

Comment: Just use a form and a submit button. (but even your ajax call makes no sense - your not even passing any data to the method)

Comment: Ok , thanks for helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you out. Redirect in Ajax call method instead of controller

1. In controller return Json

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult KategoriEkle(Kategori kategori)
   {
       KutuphaneContext db = new KutuphaneContext();
       var con = db.Kategori.Where(x => x.KategoriAdi ==     kategori.KategoriAdi).Count();

       if (con <= 0 && kategori.KategoriAdi != null)
       {                
           _kategoriRepository.Insert(kategori);
           _kategoriRepository.Save();
       }
       url = Url.Action("Kategoriler", "Kategori");
       redirect = true;

       return Json(new
       {
           redirectUrl = url,
           isRedirect = redirect
       }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
   ```
2. In Ajax Call

   ```
          $.ajax({
          url: '/Kategori/KategoriEkle',
          type: 'POST',
          data: "{}",
          datatype: 'json',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          success: function () {
          var unique_id = $.gritter.add({

           title: 'Welcome to Home!',
           text: 'Message',
           //image: '/assets/img/ui-sam.jpg',
           sticky: true,
           time: '',
           class_name: 'my-sticky-class'

           if (response.isRedirect) {
               window.location.href = response.redirectUrl;
               return false;
           }
           else {
               alert('Error occurred.');
           }
       },
       error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert(errorThrown);
       }
   ```

Comment: Wow. Thank you @Ved

Comment: It is nonsense to make an ajax call when you want to redirect

Comment: @StephenMuecke What's your advice ?

Comment: @ynsbldk, I already gave it in the comments above - just make a normal submit. The purpose of ajax is to stay on the same page, and it means you can improve performance by updating only part of a page withou need a full refresh. To write extra code in order to send data to the controller, then have the controller send data back to the client and then immediately redirect instead of making a normal post and redirecting in the controller is crazy.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I understand, before the page is renewed.Why are you angry =) Thanks for help